# Basic SQL - SELECT

Tags: c#, sql

So I've got this code:

```
query2 = "SELECT * from Clicking WHERE ID = '" + ID + "'";
```

And it seems to make problems with the script, probably I'm mistaken with something here.

For instance, when I write this:

```
query2 = "SELECT * from Clicking WHERE ID = 3";
```

..this works just fine, and the script continue with no problems. But with my original code it shows me this error:

> OleDbException was unhandled by user code
>
> An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Any suggestions how to make this work?

Comment: The first version evaluates to `SELECT * from Clicking WHERE ID = '3'` where 3 is a text not a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have the query written it will be like this:

```
SELECT * from Clicking WHERE ID = '3'
```

The '' around a number means it will look for an ID as a string that is equal to 3. So you want to remove the single quotes around the number, so it will search for a number that is equal to 3, or whatever number you use. This is what you want:

```
query2 = "SELECT * from Clicking WHERE ID = " + ID;
```

Answer (score 5):

When you use *single quotes* the `3` is treated as *string*, and probably your `ID` column is an `int`,  that's why you are getting the exception .

Also do not use string concatenation, use [parameterized queries](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) to prevent SQL injection attacks

```
query2 = "SELECT * from Clicking WHERE ID = @id";

using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(query2, connection))
{
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);  
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please elaborate a bit more about your code(excluding the first line)? And what do I need to write instead of the ... - I mean, what is mostly written there(Obviously not something specific, but an explanation would be great).